# Shapley value regression / driver analysis with binary dependent variable

Tags: regression, binary-data, importance

I've done some driver importance analyses with the `relaimpo` package in R. However, the "normal" Shapley value regressions/driver analyses/Kruskal analyses (whatever you want to name them) require a metric dependent variable, because it's an approach for linear regressions.

I have a new dataset, where I have a dependent variable with two values (0/1) and want to assess the relative importance of 10 metric independent variables.

Is anyone aware of an approach to do such a driver analysis with a binary dependent variable or knows a different approach to assess the relative importances?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the SHAP method implemented in shapr?
The link [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shapr/vignettes/understanding_shapr.html#ex) has a good documentation with examples.

Another quick and less robust way is to run simple classifier (e.g. logistic regression or decision tree), and analyze the important variables with importance() function that gives you the relative importance of the variables.

Comment: The concept of importance in Shapley regression is very different to that in a Random Forest (a Random Forest will find fewer variables as being more important, all else being equal). And, the ``importance`` function you refer to is not shipped in ``base`` R.

Comment: Sure. The references are in the answer below. Feel free to up-vote after you have read the reference.

Answer (score 1):

*Relative Importance Analysis* gives essentially the same results as Shapley (but not ask Kruskal). [A variant of Relative Importance Analysis has been developed for binary dependent variables.](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428109341993)

However, binary variables are arguable numeric, and I'd be shocked if you got a meaningfully different result from using a standard Shapley regression with your data.